# Global variable mocking in jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I've been struggling for the last couple of hours with an error within jest testing. A global variable won't let me test my component. I tried mocking the variable in several ways but nothing worked. I tried adding the "globals" atribute to my jest configuration within package.json(didn't ork). I tried mocking the variable within my test file(didn't work). Can someone give me a hand here?

This is the error im getting

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'raven_dsn' of undefined

      20 |         }
      21 |     }
    > 22 |     setExtraContext(extraContex){
      23 |         if (global.context.raven_dsn) {
      24 |             Raven.setExtraContext(extraContex);
      25 |         }

      at new Logger (realistico/frontend/react/libraries/Logger.js:22:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (realistico/frontend/react/libraries/Track.js:14:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (realistico/realpano/react/components/Viewer.jsx:35:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (realistico/newcms/react/components/StartView.js:19:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (realistico/newcms/react/components/ViewManager.js:26:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (realistico/newcms/react/components/HouseDetail.js:36:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/House.test.js:27:20)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.112s
Ran all test suites.
```

And this how the global variables that I actually could mock look like

```
(global).gettext = jest.fn(); // ==> DOES WORK
(global).window.context = jest.fn(); // ==> DOES WORK
(global).onAddhouse = jest.fn(); // ==> DOES WORK
(global).context = jest.fn(() => {});  // ==> DOESN'T WORK
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

If the global `context` is an object, you should try to initialize it within your tests as an object:

```
global.context = {};
```

Note that if you want the `raven_dsn` property to have a certain value, you will also have to define it:

```
global.context = {
    raven_dsn: 'raven_dsn_value'
};
```

Comment: Already tried this, didn't work either. This drove me nuts, so I just went the easy way

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve it the 'right' way. I just added an if statement to that specific function and it did the trick.

```
if (global.context && global.context.raven_dsn) {
     Raven.setExtraContext(extraContex);
}
```